# Ubuntu 20.04 on SSD: slow boot after first update

Tags: boot, ssd, 20.04

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a desktop (i5 8500, H370 chipset, GPU RX 570) on an Intel 128gb SSD.

The first reboot after the installation was very fast! Then I updated Ubuntu and then the boot became really slow (almost one minute with no HDD LED reactions).

What should I check?

Thanks in advance for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue editing fstab and removing a swap uuid that was not used anymore before the first reboot, after the update.

Infact, during the installation of Ubuntu, in the system I had another Ubuntu installation on a different hdd, that I formatted after booting the first time in Ubuntu.

The fstab included the other swap partition, that wasn't anymore present. So it hanged for a minute and 30 seconds on: "A start job is running for"...the missing partition.